# setImageResource don't load image

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

Good morning.
I have the following problem that I am not able to solve, and I have been after it for almost 1 month and I am going crazy.
Let me tell you. I have a sqlite database where I store fruit name and fruit photo.
I make a query to the table and I have fruit name / fruit photo stored in an array.
Until then there is no problem.
Now, I have a Recyclerview with its Adapter, in the onBindViewHolder procedure, I have a holder called FruitAdapter and an int with the position of the array.
I create 2 variables

```
String fruitphoto = fruitlist.get(position).getfruitImage
String name = fruitlist.get(position).getFruitName.
```

In both variables I have loaded a string, both the name of the fruit and the name of the photo of the fruit.
When I want to pass the variables to the holder so that it is displayed, I do the following:

```
holder.text.setText(name)
```

This works perfectly, but in the case of the image, I do the following:

```
holder.fruitimage .setImageResource(parseInt(image))
```

because setImageResource has to have an int value.
Well, the above doesn't work.
I have tried to perform:

```
string uri = "@drawable/"+image;
int ImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null,getPackageName());
holder.image.setImageResource(imageResource)
```

And I have tried more things, but none work for me.
Does anyone know how to do this? How to make that String become an int, since SetImageResource needs an int as input.

Thank you very much to all.

I need to know, please, how to solve the SetImageResource problem.
It is always the same problem, I am not able to pass the value to the procedure that it has to load

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.